# How to stop Banshee from converting my music to mp3?

Tags: banshee, convert

When I am synchronizing my music with Banshee, it stars converting my music into mp3.

How can I stop Banshee to convert my music and make it just copying it?

My player can play nearly every music format, so converting it takes a lot of time and resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah, I found a solution.

Create a file named .is_audio_player and put it in the root of your Music-Player. (the . is important!)

Then open this file (it is eventually hidden, go to the menu and allow to see hidden files) and write the following into the file:

```
output_formats=audio/ogg,audio/mp3,audio/m4a
```

This is the the solution. Here you can define, which formats you not want to have converted. For example if you want to have m4b not converted, add ,audio/m4b.

Comment: What is a "upper layer of your Music-Player."?

Comment: It just means, that the file must not be in another folder. Sorry, not my motherstongue^^

Comment: You better explain that a little better because it's still not clear where that file goes. Is it in the root of your music folder?

Comment: Yup. I'll edit it. "in the root of your music player" Is that correct english?